# Error in importing sql file [#1064]

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

I am trying to create a database for my login/signup forms. I creted this database using SQL. However, when importing it in phpmyadmin it says "Import has been successfully finished, 5 queries executed." 
then the error:
Error

SQL query:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists LoginTable(

  name varchar(100) not null,

  email varchar(100) not null default "",

  password varchar(50) not null default "", 

  age integer(50) not null,

  primary key ('email', 'password') 

)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''email', 'password') 
)' at line 7

this is my sql code:

```
drop database if exists loginInfo;
create database if not exists loginInfo;
use loginInfo;

drop table if exists LoginTable;

CREATE TABLE if not exists LoginTable(

    name varchar(100) not null,
    email varchar(100) not null,
    password varchar(50) not null,   
    age integer(50) not null,
    primary key ('email', 'password') 
);
```

Comment: `mysql` <> `sql-server`. Please only tag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: When there is a syntax error, the first thing you should do is to check the manual for syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove Single quotes in `email`, `password`.

While defining primary key you don't need to add quotes.

```
drop database if exists loginInfo;
create database if not exists loginInfo;
use loginInfo;

drop table if exists LoginTable;

CREATE TABLE if not exists LoginTable(
    name varchar(100) not null,
    email varchar(100) not null,
    password varchar(50) not null,   
    age integer(50) not null,
    primary key (email, password)
);
```